# D3.js: Chart won't fit on my bootstrap div

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, bootstrap-4

I'm facing an issue in which the "card" of bootstrap is not being responsive to my d3.chart. Please see the screenshot below of the result.

[image: chart result]

#### Chart Code

```js
const sample = [
  {
    language: 'Rust',
    value: 78.9,
    color: '#000000'
  },
  {
    language: 'Kotlin',
    value: 75.1,
    color: '#00a2ee'
  },
  {
    language: 'Python',
    value: 68.0,
    color: '#fbcb39'
  },
  {
    language: 'TypeScript',
    value: 67.0,
    color: '#007bc8'
  },
  {
    language: 'Go',
    value: 65.6,
    color: '#65cedb'
  },
  {
    language: 'Swift',
    value: 65.1,
    color: '#ff6e52'
  },
  {
    language: 'JavaScript',
    value: 61.9,
    color: '#f9de3f'
  },
  {
    language: 'C#',
    value: 60.4,
    color: '#5d2f8e'
  },
  {
    language: 'F#',
    value: 59.6,
    color: '#008fc9'
  },
  {
    language: 'Clojure',
    value: 59.6,
    color: '#507dca'
  },
  {
    language: 'JavaSpring',
    value: 100,
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    language: 'PHP',
    value: 20.96,
    color: 'red'
  }
];

const svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%");

const svgContainer = d3.select('#container');

const margin = 80;
const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

const chart = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margin + ","+ margin +")");

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(sample.map((s) => s.language))
  .padding(0.4)

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 100]);

// vertical grid lines
// const makeXLines = () => d3.axisBottom()
//   .scale(xScale)

const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)

chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

chart.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

chart.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'grid')
  .call(makeYLines()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat('')
  )

const barGroups = chart.selectAll()
  .data(sample)
  .enter()
  .append('g')

barGroups
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .attr('x', (g) => xScale(g.language))
  .attr('y', (g) => yScale(g.value))
  .attr('height', (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  .on('mouseenter', function (actual, i) {
    d3.selectAll('.value')
      .attr('opacity', 0)

    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr('opacity', 0.6)
      .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) - 5)
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() + 10)

    const y = yScale(actual.value)

    line = chart.append('line')
      .attr('id', 'limit')
      .attr('x1', 0)
      .attr('y1', y)
      .attr('x2', width)
      .attr('y2', y)

    barGroups.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'divergence')
      .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
      .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
      .attr('fill', 'white')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text((a, idx) => {
        const divergence = (a.value - actual.value).toFixed(1)

        let text = ''
        if (divergence > 0) text += '+'
        text += `${divergence}%`

        return idx !== i ? text : '';
      })

  })
  .on('mouseleave', function () {
    d3.selectAll('.value')
      .attr('opacity', 1)

    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr('opacity', 1)
      .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language))
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())

    chart.selectAll('#limit').remove()
    chart.selectAll('.divergence').remove()
  })

barGroups 
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'value')
  .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text((a) => `${a.value}%`)

svg
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('x', -(height / 2) - margin)
  .attr('y', margin / 2.4)
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text('Love meter (%)')

svg.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
  .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text('Languages')

svg.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'title')
  .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
  .attr('y', 40)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text('Most loved programming languages in 2018')

svg.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'source')
  .attr('x', width - margin / 2)
  .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
  .text('Source: Stack Overflow, 2018')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card shadow mb-5">
            <h5 class="card-header">Bar Chart</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="container">
                    <svg></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried spamming the other "card" of bootstrap with Lorem Ipsum and it seems to be working except when I put my chart inside the

Comment: can u create jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `min-height` for the graph and set `overflow: visible` to `svg`

```js
  const sample = [
    {
      language: 'Rust',
      value: 78.9,
      color: '#000000'
    },
    {
      language: 'Kotlin',
      value: 75.1,
      color: '#00a2ee'
    },
    {
      language: 'Python',
      value: 68.0,
      color: '#fbcb39'
    },
    {
      language: 'TypeScript',
      value: 67.0,
      color: '#007bc8'
    },
    {
      language: 'Go',
      value: 65.6,
      color: '#65cedb'
    },
    {
      language: 'Swift',
      value: 65.1,
      color: '#ff6e52'
    },
    {
      language: 'JavaScript',
      value: 61.9,
      color: '#f9de3f'
    },
    {
      language: 'C#',
      value: 60.4,
      color: '#5d2f8e'
    },
    {
      language: 'F#',
      value: 59.6,
      color: '#008fc9'
    },
    {
      language: 'Clojure',
      value: 59.6,
      color: '#507dca'
    },
    {
      language: 'JavaSpring',
      value: 100,
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      language: 'PHP',
      value: 20.96,
      color: 'red'
    }
  ];

  const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");

  const svgContainer = d3.select('#container');

  const margin = 80;
  const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
  const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

  const chart = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + margin + ","+ margin +")");

  const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(sample.map((s) => s.language))
    .padding(0.4)

  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 100]);

  // vertical grid lines
  // const makeXLines = () => d3.axisBottom()
  //   .scale(xScale)

  const makeYLines = () => d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale)

  chart.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

  chart.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

  chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'grid')
    .call(makeYLines()
      .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat('')
    )

  const barGroups = chart.selectAll()
    .data(sample)
    .enter()
    .append('g')

  barGroups
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', (g) => xScale(g.language))
    .attr('y', (g) => yScale(g.value))
    .attr('height', (g) => height - yScale(g.value))
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .on('mouseenter', function (actual, i) {
      d3.selectAll('.value')
        .attr('opacity', 0)

      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr('opacity', 0.6)
        .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) - 5)
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth() + 10)

      const y = yScale(actual.value)

      line = chart.append('line')
        .attr('id', 'limit')
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('y1', y)
        .attr('x2', width)
        .attr('y2', y)

      barGroups.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'divergence')
        .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text((a, idx) => {
          const divergence = (a.value - actual.value).toFixed(1)

          let text = ''
          if (divergence > 0) text += '+'
          text += `${divergence}%`

          return idx !== i ? text : '';
        })

    })
    .on('mouseleave', function () {
      d3.selectAll('.value')
        .attr('opacity', 1)

      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr('opacity', 1)
        .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language))
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())

      chart.selectAll('#limit').remove()
      chart.selectAll('.divergence').remove()
    })

  barGroups 
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'value')
    .attr('x', (a) => xScale(a.language) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr('y', (a) => yScale(a.value) + 30)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text((a) => `${a.value}%`)

  svg
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('x', -(height / 2) - margin)
    .attr('y', margin / 2.4)
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Love meter (%)')

  svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
    .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Languages')

  svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'title')
    .attr('x', width / 2 + margin)
    .attr('y', 40)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Most loved programming languages in 2018')

  svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'source')
    .attr('x', width - margin / 2)
    .attr('y', height + margin * 1.7)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
    .text('Source: Stack Overflow, 2018')
```

```css
#container {
    min-height: 37rem;
}

#container svg {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card shadow mb-5">
            <h5 class="card-header">
                Bar Chart
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="container">
                    <svg></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```